# Welding bot arm

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I am trying to build a tool that could help someone/something weld.

- Being very close to a MIG or TIG welding gun may be dangerous/undesirable.
- Welding needs to be done in a straight line (which can be difficult for some people/robots).
- Welding needs to be done pretty slowly (which can be difficult for some people/robots).

As a Bear of Very Little Brain I thought to myself:

- With [Scott Russell's linkage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zH3wK5gEWPw) I can create some distance between the user and the object being welded and this will also ensure a perfect straight line.
- With [a pantograph](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/w6y4I4OHiok) I can turn a large movement into a much smaller movement.

So I basically have these 2 mechanisms:

[image: Text]

- I think the user/robot should use (C).
- (J) can hold the welding gun
- (B) can be connected to (H).

I think that would achieve these goals, but it would be better if I could combine them without sticking one on top of the other and I'm sure this design can be improved. Do you have any suggestions how to simplify and/or improve this design?

Comment: extend the BD link ... B is same as H

Comment: @jsotola Thank you. My brain just refuses to do any work after welding all day. If you turn that into an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Section ABD is same as section GHI.

Extend the BD link to match HIJ.

Constrain C, instead of B.